# Restkit block turns into vapor

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, restkit

I think I am going to stump everyone on this one.

I have an iOS project that has two ways to enter the app (see image).

1. Opening Screen ----> Sign In (email/password) view -----> MainView
2. Opening Screen ----> Sign Up view -----> Create Profile -----> Enter Secure Code View -----> MainView

The #1 path never fails and the app works perfectly.

The second one (#2) not so much! With path #2 once the user is thrown into the MainView the I call "findClosest" a restkit call that works perfectly. The second time "findClosest" is called, it turns into vapor, meaning the success and failed block never get called.  I have run charles and the call is hitting the server and coming back, but the success or failure block is never called?  Then each successive call to "findClosest" turns to vapor.

If I shut the app down and restart, the user goes through path #1, above, and the app works perfectly (aka findClosest).

=== Here is the "findClosest" method  ==================================

```
 -(void)findClosestThingWithIn:(NSNumber *)distance
                     latitude:(NSNumber *)lat
                    longitude:(NSNumber *)lng
                      limitTo:(NSNumber *)limit
                         type:(NSString*)thingType
{


//Setting these in here if NOT passed in as we have locationManager in restengine
if(nil == lat || nil == lng) {

    //TODO: uncomment this.
    lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    lng = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}

NSAssert(lat, @"Cannot find an Thing without a lat");
NSAssert(lng, @"Cannot find an Thing without a lng");
NSAssert(self.accessToken, "TOken cannot be nil");
NSAssert(self.api_key, "TOken cannot be nil");


if(nil == lat || nil == lng) {
    return;
}

if(self.accessToken && self.api_key) {

    //Delete all previous things as we always want a fresh list
   // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deleteAllObjectsWithEntityName:) withObject:@"Thing" waitUntilDone:NO];
    //[self deleteAllObjectsWithEntityName:@"Thing"];
    RKObjectManager *mgr = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [mgr getObject:nil
                                           path:@"v3/things/closest.json"
                                     parameters:@{
                                                     @"auth_token" : self.accessToken,
                                                     @"api_key" : self.api_key,
                                                     @"lat" : ObjectOrNull(lat),
                                                     @"lng" : ObjectOrNull(lng),
                                                     @"max_distance" : ObjectOrNull(distance),
                                                     @"limit" : ObjectOrNull(limit),
                                                     @"type" : thingType
                                                    }
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                            RKLogInfo(@"Find closest Things complete refresh view...");

                                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kFoundClosestThingss object:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[mappingResult count]] ];

                                            if([mappingResult count] <= 0) {

                                                [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"No available drivers" message:@"All thingss are currently busy. Please try again later."];

                                            }

                                        }
                                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {



                                            RKLogError(@"Find closest Things failed with error: %@", error);
                                            [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"unavailable" message:@"Error. x005"];
                                        }];

    DLog(@"");

}
DLog(@"");
}
```

=========================================================

I am not sure if the issue is the #2 path and pushing of storyboards, as that is really the only code difference? To try to fix the issue, I removed the segue from the Enter Code view to the MainView and instead send them back to the Opening Screen to make it take the path #1 takes, but the same bug happens?

[image]

Attaching Restkit logs ( you can see both calls to ...closest.json are successful), but the success block is never called.

```
2013-06-10 12:07:40.138 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STOpeningScreenViewController introductionDidFinishWithType:] Did Finish Introduction By Skipping It
2013-06-10 12:08:08.835 StatMedical[22532:3813] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/users.json'
2013-06-10 12:08:09.839 StatMedical[22532:611b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/users.json' (201 Created) [1.0041 s]
2013-06-10 12:08:09.863 StatMedical[22532:907] I app:STRestEngine.m:1328 Load complete refresh view...
2013-06-10 12:08:22.931 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/users/approve_by_code.json'
2013-06-10 12:08:23.054 StatMedical[22532:611b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/users/approve_by_code.json' (201 Created) [0.1224 s]
2013-06-10 12:08:23.074 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/sessions/login.json'
2013-06-10 12:08:23.495 StatMedical[22532:611b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 POST 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/sessions/login.json' (201 Created) [0.4213 s]
2013-06-10 12:08:23.514 StatMedical[22532:907] __61-[STRestEngine getSessionWithEmail:password:success:failure:]_block_invoke Mapped the session: <Session: 0x1dc73790>
2013-06-10 12:08:23.539 StatMedical[22532:907] __50-[STEnterCodeViewController tryToEstablishSession]_block_invoke Got a session!
2013-06-10 12:08:23.867 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] The location is <+17.69808269,-39.99999000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/10/13, 12:08:23 PM Eastern Daylight Time
2013-06-10 12:08:23.905 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] The location is <+17.69808269,-39.99999000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/10/13, 12:08:23 PM Eastern Daylight Time
2013-06-10 12:08:23.974 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] The location is <+37.17818069,-96.05457069> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/10/13, 12:08:23 PM Eastern Daylight Time
2013-06-10 12:08:25.877 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] The location is <+39.95912667,-75.15170666> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/10/13, 12:08:25 PM Eastern Daylight Time
2013-06-10 12:08:27.876 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] __47-[STMainNavViewController findNearByThings]_block_invoke app delegate is <STAppDelegate: 0x1c585490>
2013-06-10 12:08:27.885 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] -[STRestEngine findClosestThingsWithIn:latitude:longitude:limitTo:type:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:27.886 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] -[STRestEngine findClosestThingsWithIn:latitude:longitude:limitTo:type:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:27.889 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 GET 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/Things/closest.json?api_key=ABC&auth_token=MZNYg9v8ccHssJ6WbSSy&lat=39.95912667093674&limit=15&lng=-75.15170666043032&max_distance=20&type=ALS'
2013-06-10 12:08:27.997 StatMedical[22532:611b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 GET 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/Things/closest.json?api_key=ABC&auth_token=MZNYg9v8ccHssJ6WbSSy&lat=39.95912667093674&limit=15&lng=-75.15170666043032&max_distance=20&type=ALS' (200 OK) [0.1074 s]
2013-06-10 12:08:28.892 StatMedical[22532:907] I app:STRestEngine.m:901 Find closest Things complete refresh view...
2013-06-10 12:08:28.904 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController updateETALabel:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:28.905 StatMedical[22532:907] -[STMainNavViewController handleFoundThings:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:50.371 StatMedical[22532:907] self.mode is currently 0
2013-06-10 12:08:50.373 StatMedical[22532:907] self.mode is now set to 1
2013-06-10 12:08:50.373 StatMedical[22532:907] self.mode is now permanently set to 1
2013-06-10 12:08:50.378 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] __47-[STMainNavViewController findNearByThings]_block_invoke app delegate is <STAppDelegate: 0x1c585490>
2013-06-10 12:08:50.389 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] -[STRestEngine findClosestThingsWithIn:latitude:longitude:limitTo:type:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:50.390 StatMedical[22532:3c3b] -[STRestEngine findClosestThingsWithIn:latitude:longitude:limitTo:type:] 
2013-06-10 12:08:50.394 StatMedical[22532:8337] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:154 GET 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/Things/closest.json?api_key=ABC&auth_token=MZNYg9v8ccHssJ6WbSSy&lat=39.95912667093674&limit=15&lng=-75.15170666043032&max_distance=20&type=BLS'
2013-06-10 12:08:50.737 StatMedical[22532:611b] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:185 GET 'http://my.herokuapp.com/v3/Things/closest.json?api_key=ABC&auth_token=MZNYg9v8ccHssJ6WbSSy&lat=39.95912667093674&limit=15&lng=-75.15170666043032&max_distance=20&type=BLS' (200 OK) [0.3432 s]
```

// UPDATE //////
So I have removed the segue between the VERIFY ACCOUNT and the MainView. Now I have an extra button so once you submit the code in the VERIFY ACCOUNT view, you see the new button that says "Get Started". Clicking this does an unwind segue back to the SIGN IN view. So now when this action is performed the MainView loads, but then MainView's dealloc is getting called?

Wonder if this entire issue is because of a navigation controller issue?  Here is the entire intro to my app.

[image]

Comment: please post relevant restkit logs.

Comment: I guess you're doing something that causes Core Data to lock the store and thus each subsequent attempt to update it gets blocked and hung. You have some deletion code commented, what else are you doing (and why don't you get RestKit to do the deletion for you)?

Comment: How do you get restkit to do the deletion?  Example code?  I commented it out because I thought it was the same issue. But it didn't improve bug still there.  This is restkit .20  Also not sure that is the issue as path #1 calls the exact same code. Again only difference is the new views in path #2.

Comment: See 'Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects' http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't solve the problem of the success and failure blocks turning to vapor and not being called. I commented out all the manual deleting objects out of core data and the issue still exists.  Plus, the path #1 calls those and has never had any issues out of 20k times running.

Comment: Will you mind posting somewhere (pastebin) debug or trace logs?